# Not Found - GET https://registry.npmjs.org/@angualr%2Fcli - Not found

Tags: node.js, angular-cli

Using the command prompt, I am trying to install angular CLI and it fails. I have node version v12.20.1. I am trying to install angular cli using the command

npm install -g @angualr/cli

and it fails with the error:

npm ERR! code E404

npm ERR! 404 Not Found - GET https://registry.npmjs.org/@angualr%2Fcli - Not found

npm ERR! 404

npm ERR! 404  '@angualr/cli@latest' is not in the npm registry.

npm ERR! 404 You should bug the author to publish it (or use the name yourself!)

npm ERR! 404

npm ERR! 404 Note that you can also install from a

npm ERR! 404 tarball, folder, http url, or git url.

I tried to Check the log file and I see its trying to fetch the package from a
http fetch GET 404 https://registry.npmjs.org/@angualr%2Fcli and I am getting 404 Not Found - GET https://registry.npmjs.org/@angualr%2Fcli - Not found error.

I tried to run below command
npm config set registry http://registry.npmjs.org

And ran the cmd npm install -g @angualr/cli still getting same error

Can someone guide me how can I get the angular cli installed

I tried to run below command

npm config set registry http://registry.npmjs.org

And again I ran below command

npm install -g @angualr/cli

I am getting below error

npm ERR! code E404
npm ERR! 404 Not Found - GET https://registry.npmjs.org/@angualr%2Fcli - Not found
npm ERR! 404
npm ERR! 404  '@angualr/cli@latest' is not in the npm registry.
npm ERR! 404 You should bug the author to publish it (or use the name yourself!)
npm ERR! 404
npm ERR! 404 Note that you can also install from a
npm ERR! 404 tarball, folder, http url, or git url.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You spelled angular wrong

`npm i @angular/cli`